# What are the essential things that a new ubuntu server should have installed, for development purposes?

Tags: linux, unix

```
sudo apt-get install build-essential
```

What else?

Comment: What are you developing in?  java/python/c++?

Comment: By development server, do you mean a machine that you are developing a webapp on? Or one that you want to publish webapp code to?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For any sort of web development, I would recommend `apache2`. For databases, I would recommend `mysql-server` or `postgresql`. For Java (as well as C++ and some others), a popular option is `eclipse`, although `netbeans` is also good.

If you want to see what's going on under the hood, `wireshark` is a great network monitoring utility that shows you every detail of all network traffic for the server.